# write WinProc event handler in a different class

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have to handle windows events in my `WPF` application. To do so, I have setup `projectName_SourceInitialized` like this:

```
private void FieldPlannerWnd_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr windowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow)).Handle;
    HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
    src.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
}
```

For this, my `WndProc` function has to be in the same class (`MainWindow` class).
The message that my `WndProc` is going to handle is coming from legacy code which will basically send this class a POINT in Lparam and Wparam. I have to share that POINT with my USER CONTROL's class  which is set as the data context of this `MainWindow` class. This is how my `WndProc` procedure looks like:

```
private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_POINTDATASENT:
        //gm.GAInfo = new GAInfo();
        PointsVector pt = new PointsVector();
        pt.X = wParam.ToInt32();
        pt.Y = lParam.ToInt32();
        //WellGeometriesView.FirstSlotLocation = pt;
        //WellGeometriesViewModel.FirstSlotLocation = pt;
        //gm.GetCoordinates(wParam, lParam);

        break;
     }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Since I can't not have any member variable of USER Control's class here in my Main Window's class, so how can I share this POINT data received in WndProc with UserControl's class? One way that I could think of was to add the WndProc event handler in the User Control's class but that class does not contain _SourceInitialized event handler. How can I do that? Is there any other good way possible?

*P.S*: All members of USER CONTROLS's class are non-static and I am trying to follow MVVM structure.

Comment: Would it be possible to put the point data in the DataContext of the Window and have the UserControl pull the data from its parent by a binding or by code (parent.DataContext)?

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that & it solved the problem for me. many thanks for this @ErnodeWeerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the point data in the DataContext of the Window and have the UserControl pull the data from its parent by a binding or by code (parent.DataContext)